# statistical test to compare numerical data pre and post intervention

Tags: t-test, causality, paired-data

For my research I will be comparing the mean number of screening tests performed before implementation of an intervention and after.  The pre and post groups are not the exact same participants.  The data is numerical and discrete.  I am thinking I would use an unpaired t test, but Which statistical test would you suggest I use for this project?  Thanks so much for any guidance!

Comment: Do you have concurrent controls and were people randomized to control or intervention? If not, some simple test will typically inappropriate(even if it's the same individuals before and after) and some serious help from some epidemilogist (or similar person very experienced with observational/non-randomized experiments) is needed, because it will be very hard to do this in a way that excludes all other possible explanations for differences in tests. That is, if you want to say anything about the intervention's effectiveness (I assume you do, otherwise a pre- / post-comparison seems useless)